# spark-submit cluster mode is not working

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting an error in launching the standalone Spark driver in cluster mode. As per the documentation, it is noted that cluster mode is supported in the Spark 1.2.1 release. However, it is currently not working properly for me. Please help me in fixing the issue(s) that are preventing the proper functioning of Spark.
I have 3 node spark cluster node1 , node2 and node 3

```
I running below command on node 1 for deploying driver

/usr/local/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit --class com.fst.firststep.aggregator.FirstStepMessageProcessor --master spark://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --supervise file:///home/xyz/sparkstreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/xyz/config.properties

driver gets launched on node 2 in cluster. but getting exception on node 2 that it is trying to bind to node 1 ip.

2015-02-26 08:47:32 DEBUG AkkaUtils:63 - In createActorSystem, requireCookie is: off 
2015-02-26 08:47:32 INFO  Slf4jLogger:80 - Slf4jLogger started 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 ERROR NettyTransport:65 - failed to bind to ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:0, shutting down Netty transport 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 WARN  Utils:71 - Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1. 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 DEBUG AkkaUtils:63 - In createActorSystem, requireCookie is: off 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 ERROR Remoting:65 - Remoting error: [Startup failed] [ 
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup failed 
        at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:136) 
        at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:201) 
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1765) 
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1756) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:33) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala) 
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: ec2-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:0 
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272) 
        at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393) 
        at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389) 
        at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206) 
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) 
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206) 
kindly suggest

Thanks`enter code here`
```

Comment: Try adding -Dspark.driver.port=3210 (or any other port) when submitting the job

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to bind to port 0. There is/are errors in your spark configuration. Specifically look at the

```
spark.webui.port
```

It is probably set to 0.